# why do we need ClassMethods and InstanceMethods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I read the [API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) for ActiveSupport::Concern. There are `ClassMethods` and `InstanceMethods`, we can put class methods in `ClassMethods`.

But the `M`'s host can use the methods defined in `M`, can't it? Why can't I just write:

```
module M
  def self.x
  end

  def y
  end
end
```

rather than:

```
module M
  module ClassMethods
    def x
    end
  end
  module InstanceMethods
    def y
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You might be interested in [Yehuda's take on this pattern](http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/). I think the reason for some of it is historical, since they're not really needed unless you're doing manually what Ruby will do automatically through `include` and `extend`.

Answer (score 3):

Dependencies are taken care of.  See the example provided [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html).